# How do I set all the diagonals in a matrix equal to zero?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, matrix

I have a problem with my homework that asks me to have the compiler print out a matrix in which all the diagonals are outputted as zero. I also have to pass it to a function. However, I have no idea how to do this..
Here is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int diagonals();

int main()
{
    //problem 1
    int matrix[3][3];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3 ; j++)
        {
            cout << "Row " << i << " column " << j<< ": ";
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nReverse of the matrix:" << endl;

    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }//end of problem 1

    //problem 2

    cout << "Diagonals changed to 0:\n" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hint: for an array `a[n]`, the first element is `a[0]` and the last element is `a[n-1]`. This means it has to be `for (int i=0; i<3; i++)`  and `for (int j=0; j<3; j++)`in your case.

Answer (score 0):

your matrix declaration says  `int matrix[3][3];` that it has three 1-D array & in each 1-D array you can store three elements. And in `C/C++` array index starts from `zero`.

Problematic statement is `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)` as you are skipping `matrix[0][0]` and trying to store into `matrix[3][3]` which doesn't exist which in turn causes **undefined** behavior.

So firstly start iterating loop from `0` to number of `rows` & column respectively.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {
                cout << "Row " << i << " column " << j<< ": ";
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
}
```

Coming to task you mentioned, *print out a matrix in which all the diagonals are outputted as zero. ?* write one condition so that if `row` value & `col` value are equal then assign it to `zero` otherwise scan from user. Here is the sample code

```
int main(void) {
        int matrix[3][3] = { 0 }; /* initialize it */
        int row  = sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(matrix[0]); /* find no of rows */
        int col  = sizeof(matrix[0])/sizeof(matrix[0][0]);/* find no of columns */

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)   {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)   {
                        if( i == j)
                                matrix[i][j] = 0;/* when i and j are equal means thats diagonal and assign it to zero */
                        else /* if its not diagonal then scan from user */
                                std::cin>>matrix[i][j];

                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**Secondly**, *I also have to pass it to a function.* for this learn how to pass 2d array to a function. Here is the sample example.

```
void diagonal(int (*mat)[3],int row, int col) { /* mat is pointer to an array */
        std::cout<<"printing matrix "<<std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)   {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)   {
                        std::cout<<mat[i][j]<<"\t";             
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
}
```

And call `diagonal()` like below from `main()` function as

```
diagonal(matrix,row,col); /* pass matrix, no of rows, no of columns */
```

Comment: Strongly recommend pointing out that most of the Asker's confusion came from trying to use Origin One indexing with arrays.